# The life of a machine ($x$) has an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$. What is the expected life of the machine given that $x > 1$

Tags: probability

Could someone please explain the solution:

Solution:

$E[X | X > 1] = \int_{1}^{\infty} x f_{X|X>1}(x | x > 1)dx$

$F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$

$F_{X | X > 1}(x | x > 1) = P(X \leq x | x > 1) = \frac{P(X \leq x, X > 1)}{P(X > 1)} = \frac{F_{X}(x) - F_{X}(1)}{1 - F_{X}(1)}$

$= \frac{F_{X}(x)}{1-F_{X}(1)} - \frac{F_{X}(1)}{1-F_{X}(1)}$

thus,

$f_{X | X > 1}(x | x > 1) = \frac{f_{X}(x)}{1-F_{X}(1)} - 0 = \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-1}} = e^{-(x-1)}$

$E(X | X > 1) = \int_{1}^{\infty} x f_{X | X > 1} (x | x > 1))dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} x e^{-(x-1)}dx = 2$ (by int by parts dont really need to show it)

---

I get how they got the equation $E[X | X > 1] = \int_{1}^{\infty} x f_{X|X>1}(x | x > 1)dx$

I don't get how they used the CDF to get $f_{X | X > 1}(x | x > 1)$. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is $x$? You have also not specified the distribution governing $X$.

Comment: Sorry fixed it, it was exponential dist with lambda = 1.

Comment: PDF is simply derived by differentiating the CDF. The second term in your $F_X(x)$ is constant, so it goes away when you differentiate. The first term is ${F_X(x) \over 1-F_X(1)}$, which when differentiated gives ${f_X(x) \over 1-F_X(1)}$.

Comment: ok, but how does $1-F_{X}(1) = e^{-1}$?

Comment: Because is $X \sim exp(1)$, $F_X(x) = 1-e^{-x}$, so $F_X(1) = 1-e^{-1}$.